# SqlConnection не реагирует на password

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

Имеется база данных на Sql Server 2012. 
В базе данных имеется пользователь TestUser, созданный таким образом:

```
CREATE LOGIN TestUser
    WITH PASSWORD = '123';
USE Банк;
GO
CREATE USER TestUser FOR LOGIN TestUser;
GO
```

Я подключаюсь к базе через приложение на C#, используя SqlConnection.

```
String ConnectionString = "Data Source=Computer;Initial Catalog=Банк;Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID=TestUser;Password=123;";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
con.Open();
```

Проблема в том что даже если пароль неверный то соединение все равно будет установлено и можно отправлять запросы. Подскажите как это исправить.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте убрать "Integrated Security=SSPI". Кажется это логинит через системный логин и соосно игнорит юзера и пароль. То есть вы входите не как TestUser.